# iOS App build number and version number is swapped

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Long story short, I have an app in the app store that has the build number and version number swapped.

ie: 
Version - 412 
Build - 3.0.1.412

What I want is to have the version to be 3.0.1 and build number to be 412.

If I try to submit the app with the correct numbers, AppLoader would give me an a "Invalid CFBundleVersion" error.

Does anyone have a solution to this, or if anyone knows I can email Apple to have them reset my version details/history?

Comment: I am in the exact same boat. Did you get this resolved at all?

Comment: At least you set the version number that is displayed from ITC I guess.